# Returning results from angularjs resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

If I have a factory where I want to return all tasks:

```
App.factory('Task', function(TaskResource) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      TaskResource.query().then(function(results) {
        return results;
      }  
    }
  };
});
```

and I try to use it in the "TasksController":

```
App.controller('TasksController', function('Task') {
  $scope.tasks = Task.all();
});
```

I get the result of 'undefined'. If I log the results in the factory itself, they return correctly. Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TaskResource.query()` is a promise. `.then` on the promise returns after some time. What that means is the `all` function returns immediately, returning `undefined`. Promise completes after some time and returns the result which nobody gets! That is the reason why you see `undefined` returned from `all` function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know how I could modify this so that it would return the result of the promise?

Comment: Since your return value depends on a promise, you should return a  promise as a result of `all` function. You may return `TaskResource.query()` promise or return a new promise and resolve it when `TaskResource.query()` resolves.